# Rundeck env variables work for Ubuntu but not for CentOS machines

Tags: rundeck

I have exported few env variables in /etc/sysconfig/rundeckd for CentOS and /etc/default/rundeckd for Ubuntu. The vars seem to be accessed in Ubuntu rdcli but not in centos. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The configuration must be set in the user shell (for example at `.bashrc` file), check the configuration documentation [here](https://rundeck.github.io/rundeck-cli/configuration/).

Look:

```
export RD_URL=http://192.168.33.10:4440
export RD_USER=admin
export RD_PASSWORD=admin
```

Comment: The variables are exported in usershell by sourcing the /etc/sysconfig/rundeckd file. But still I get "Input error for [rd run run]: Environment variable RD_URL is required: Please specify the Rundeck base URL, e.g. http://host:port or http://host:port/api/14"